# Is is possible to get the last file updated in folder and subfolder with specifique name in artifactory?

Tags: python, shell, curl, artifactory

I'm looking to find a solution how I can get the path of the last file updated with name "name_file" in specifique folder and subfolder in artifactory directory.
From documentation, I see this link https://jfrog.com/help/r/jfrog-rest-apis/get-last-modified-item but I can't specify the file name as in my root folder I can have a lot of files the same name in the differents subfolders.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to achieve this is by using the [JFrog CLI](https://docs.jfrog-applications.jfrog.io/jfrog-applications/jfrog-cli):

```
jf rt s "<repository-name>/<path-in-repository>/" --sort-by modified --sort-order desc --limit 1
```

- Download JFrog CLI here - https://jfrog.com/getcli/.

Another option is to run [AQL](https://jfrog.com/help/r/jfrog-artifactory-documentation/artifactory-query-language) (Artifactory Query Language) via REST API:

`POST /artifactory/api/search/aql`

```json
items.find({"$and":[{"repo":"<repository-name>","path":{"$match":"<path-in-repository>"} }]}).include("name","repo","path","modified").sort({"$desc":["modified"]}).limit(1)
```